# Question on Cantor's Intersection Theorem Proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm confused about the complexity of this proof. If we have some set $C_i, i\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $C_0\supset C_1\supset ... $, we do we need these sets to be non-empty, closed, and compact to conclude that $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}C_i \ne \emptyset$?

Why isn't the nested sets condition enough for this intersection to hold? Since they're all nested subsets of the preceding set, they all must share an element, no? I assume I am missing something very obvious here. Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Consider $C_n = (0, 1/n)$. These are nested, but the intersection $\bigcap C_n$ is empty.

Comment: For a closed but not compact example, take $C_n = [n,\infty)$.

Comment: @Bungo Ah, that makes a lot of sense, thank you. So, these intersections would not be empty assuming the intersection is finite, right? Also, what if the nest was in the other direction (i.e. $C_0 \subset C_1 \subset ...$)? Would that change anything? Thanks.

Comment: Correct, for a finite nesting $C_0 \supset C_1 \supset \cdots C_k$, we have $\bigcap_{n=0}^{k} = C_k$. For a finite or infinite nesting in the other direction, $\bigcap C_n = C_0$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks. One last question if you don't mind: does the indexing matter at all? For example, if the nesting is in the other direction, you say that $\bigcap C_n = C_0$. However, what if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ instead of $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In this case, I assume we are back to needing the sets to be compact and closed, because we have no $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $C_i \subset C_k,  \forall k \in \mathbb{Z} $ ?

Comment: Correct, for nesting of the form $C_0 \supset C_1 \supset \ldots$, there is a first set in the indexing, and that first set is the largest set. There is in general no smallest set. For nesting in the opposite direction $C_0 \subset C_1 \subset \ldots$, there is again a first set in the indexing, and in this case the first set is the smallest set. In general there is no largest set. If you have a nesting of the form $\ldots C_{-1} \subset C_0 \subset C_1 \ldots$ (in either direction) then there is no first or last set, and in general no smallest or largest set.

Comment: In cases where there is a smallest set, then the intersection equals the smallest set. In cases where there is a largest set, then the union equals the largest set. If there is no smallest set, then the intersection will be smaller than any of the sets in the sequence. If there is no largest set, then the union will be larger than any of the sets in the sequence.

Comment: Of course! So given that the sets are compact and closed, in the case where $C_{-1} \subset C_0 \subset C_1$, the problem can be broken down into Cantor's Intersection Theorem for $n < 0$ and the simple fact that $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} C_n = C_0$ for $n>0$ to prove that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} C_k \ne \emptyset$, right? Thanks a ton for your help, you've cleared a lot of things up, I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Glad to help!

Comment: @Bungo You should post those comments as an answer!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Agree, I was planning to write a proper answer when I have a bit more time, hopefully later this evening!